# Unable to hide the Toolbar + Recycler View

Tags: android, toolbar, material-design

i Created a Tool bar without using Collapsing Toolbar. I need to hide the toolbar  on scrolling up the Recycler view.i followed link for scrolling/hiding toolbar

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html

Here is my xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" /></android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here is my output
[image]
I am Not sure where its going wrong. I did every thing correctly . But on scrolling the recycler view the Toolbar stays at the same position. Its not hiding.

Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are known issues with using  using `wrap_content` for your `Toolbar`. Instead, use a fixed height:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />
```

You'll note I use `scroll|enterAlways` - `exitUntilCollapsed` only makes sense when you are using a `CollapsingToolbarLayout` (or any layout that has a different `layout_height` and `minHeight`).

Comment: app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"  is worked for me. The Toolbar got hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure 
`build.gradle` has  at least `buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"`
and

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0'
```